# How to update data in sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

Basically I have made an app which is a quiz type app. At every `Activity` 1 single question appears. Since I'm using `ViewPager` adapter  and answers are to be chosen in the form of radio buttons, I am having trouble how to store the answers in the database and if the user goes back on previous question again and changes that answer I need to update the database accordingly.

How to manage these all things in sqlite database?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the answer of the question using the question id, so first find the question id which one is user select for update the answer, then update the table in SqlLite using the given code.

```
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Quiz", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("update tableName SET answerFields WHERE pk_id='"+id+"' and userId='"+userid+"'");
    db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas when the user is selecting the checkbox you would be adding the entry with a key(primary key or question id) and a boolean value to indicate if it is selected or not , you can check when the viewpager loads if a question has been answered or not , on unselect of the checkbox you can update the value in the db to false , hope this helps you.